# macOSアプリでのNSDatePickerの表示を[月/日/時/分]形式にしたい

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, xcode8

画像のように設定したのですが、年/月/日/時/分になっており、年が表示されてしまいます。
これを年を無くし[月/日/時/分]表示にするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？
Elementsでは対処することができずわかりません、よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboardエディターで表示されるElementsの項目は、`NSDatePicker`のこちらのプロパティに対応するようです。

> ## [datePickerElements](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdatepicker/1533480-datepickerelements)
>
> A bitmask that indicates which visual elements of the date picker are
> currently shown, and which won't be usable because they are hidden.
>
> ### Discussion
>
> See “Constants” in [NSDatePickerCell](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdatepickercell) for a description of the possible values.

リンク先を辿ると、使用可能な定数の一覧が出てきます。

> ## [NSDatePickerElementFlags](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdatepickerelementflags)
>
> #### Constants
>
> ```
> static var hourMinuteDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the hour and minute elements of the date.
>
> ```
> static var hourMinuteSecondDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the hour, minute and second elements of
> the date.
>
> ```
> static var timeZoneDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the time zone.
>
> ```
> static var yearMonthDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the year and month elements of the date.
>
> ```
> static var yearMonthDayDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the year, month and day elements of the
> date.
>
> ```
> static var eraDatePickerElementFlag: NSDatePickerElementFlags
> ```
>
> Display and allow editing of the era of the date, if applicable.

定義されているのは、上記6つの定数だけです。MonthとDayだけを定義した定数がないのは、英語の説明部分を読まなくてもすぐにお分かりだと思います。

最初のプロパティの説明にあるように、こちらの値は bitmask なので、月と日に対応すると思われるビットだけを設定してみたのですが、そのような不正な値を指定すると **日付部分自体が全く表示されなくなってしまいました**。

私の試し方・探し方が悪かっただけという可能性もありますが、**`NSDatePicker`は、年を省いた「月/日」の形式で日付部分を表示・編集することはできないようにデザインされている** と考えた方が良いように思います。

どうしても「月/日」の表示にしたければ、`NSDatePicker`を使わず、他のコントロールを組み合わせたり、カスタムコントロールを自作する必要があるでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
自前での実装をしたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

iOSではなく、macOSのNSDatePickerですよね？

Appleの公式ドキュメントを見る限り、
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdatepickerelementflags
「年」抜きの「月/日」は用意されていないようです。
おそらく、2/29が問題になるためかと思われます

ですので、

> これを年を無くし[月/日/時/分]表示にするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

については「月/日」は自前で実装してやる必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
自作で実装を目指します